# High, variable ping times to machine on local network

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ping

I have two machines on my local network, both connected to a wireless router. From machine A, if I ping my router, I get this:

```
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9038ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.836/2.488/3.749/0.931 ms
```

From machine B, if I ping my router, I get this:

```
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9017ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.068/3.452/4.908/0.795 ms
```

But if I ping B from A, I get

```
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9010ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.077/223.724/507.174/186.355 ms
```

with similar results for pinging A from B.

What could possibly be causing this, and how would I fix it? Both machines use Arch Linux, fully up to date.

Comment: What happens if you have both machines ping each other – or have A ping B while B is also continuously downloading something? I'm guessing it's just the Wi-Fi radio going into powersave mode.

Comment: It seems from your min ping that a fast connection could be possible. Depending on your location and how many other clients/APs are around you [CSMA/CD](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/know-how/csmacd-carrier-sense-multiple-access-collision-detection/) could play a role here. You might want to check the utilization of the wifi channels and change your APs channel to a less populated one. Also check if your AP is showing wifi packet error statistics.

Comment: @user1686: That does not appear to change my results.

Comment: How about `iw wlan0 set power_save off` then?

Comment: @user1686: Make that an answer and I'll accept it. `rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.893/4.589/5.348/0.429 ms`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wi-Fi hardware will usually try to enter a low-power state as much as possible, during which the AP will buffer packets and the client device will only check for waiting incoming packets at certain intervals:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/automatic-power-save-delivery-apsd
- https://documentation.meraki.com/MR/WiFi_Basics_and_Best_Practices/Power_Saving_Technologies

When the machine *sends* a ping packet first, its Wi-Fi interface will stay online for a while expecting a response to arrive, so there will not be any significant latency. But when the machine is completely idle and is about to *receive* the first packet from another device, it won't immediately see that you're trying to ping it until the next poll, which could take a long time.

If you expect to use the machine as a server (on AC power, accepting incoming SSH or other connections) you can disable the power save features using:

```
iw dev wlan0 set power_save off
```

This can be added to a udev rule to apply it on every boot, or an acpid script to apply it whenever the system is connected to AC. (It *can* impact battery life though, so I would not disable it just for the sake of making `ping mylaptop` look nicer). I'm writing this while halfway asleep.

Comment: I had to use `iw dev wlan0 set power_save off`